# CSR Signature fails but can be verified manually

Tags: go, ecdsa, csr

I am quite stuck with my CSR signature verification in go.
I am not able to verify my signature with csr.checkSignature() but I can verify it manually.

My go version is 1.19.4 (No control here)

Here is my procedure on creating the CSR as mentioned here: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/237392/how-is-public-key-included-in-the-csr

1- CSR Info (CA info):

```
3081b2020100301e310b3009060355040613025553310f300d060355040a13065350494646453059301306072a8648ce3d020106082a8648ce3d030107034200046a2093d1601db0774023bb6eca471970f1e041d6a5cf4aeeb1402c139d4511cdd554dadc9a3f95ff9be5a2139ce84d5bb1670525804456ba9a1f95f6f44062bca032303006092a864886f70d01090e31233021301f0603551d110418301686147370696666653a2f2f6578616d706c652e6f7267
```

2- Hash these info with sha 256:

```
267f33f4035ae98b938aa0477c2831095f3656251f6d68628ae23d4a394731bb
```

3- Send this hash to my third party backend signature service (that hash again with sha256 the data, no control here)

```
304402206ce9ca4902702ffa9663f1f9c4139cfefae89ef1ce88cae733f1d2be9ddee410022060d9c8039b0bc8a0c15b4d745df259aed22166038ca9349beb80f0cb7f2908c7
```

The right private key is selected for the sign operation.

4- I end up with a CSR in DER format: (Well formatted I believe)

```
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
```

in base64:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----
MIIBCjCBsgIBADAeMQswCQYDVQQGEwJVUzEPMA0GA1UEChMGU1BJRkZFMFkwEwYH
KoZIzj0CAQYIKoZIzj0DAQcDQgAEaiCT0WAdsHdAI7tuykcZcPHgQdalz0rusUAs
E51FEc3VVNrcmj+V/5vlohOc6E1bsWcFJYBEVrqaH5X29EBivKAyMDAGCSqGSIb3
DQEJDjEjMCEwHwYDVR0RBBgwFoYUc3BpZmZlOi8vZXhhbXBsZS5vcmcwCgYIKoZI
zj0EAwIDRwAwRAIgbOnKSQJwL/qWY/H5xBOc/vronvHOiMrnM/HSvp3e5BACIGDZ
yAObC8igwVtNdF3yWa7SIWYDjKk0m+uA8Mt/KQjH
-----END CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----
```

This CSR can be parsed without error with:

```
csr, err = x509.ParseCertificateRequest(csrDER)
```

The Validation of the CSR is done like this:

```
func ValidateCSR(csr *x509.CertificateRequest) error {
if err := csr.CheckSignature(); err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("CSR signature check failed: %w", err)
    }
}
```

The CSR decoder website below cannot verify the signature:
https://redkestrel.co.uk/products/decoder/

Now, my public key:
Public key on the curve primev256, and its counter part has been used to sign the data.

```
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MFkwEwYHKoZIzj0CAQYIKoZIzj0DAQcDQgAEaiCT0WAdsHdAI7tuykcZcPHgQdal
z0rusUAsE51FEc3VVNrcmj+V/5vlohOc6E1bsWcFJYBEVrqaH5X29EBivA==
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

in asn1 DER format:

```
3059301306072A8648CE3D020106082A8648CE3D030107034200046A2093D1601DB0774023BB6ECA471970F1E041D6A5CF4AEEB1402C139D4511CDD554DADC9A3F95FF9BE5A2139CE84D5BB1670525804456BA9A1F95F6F44062BC
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong here. All seems ok for me, but it is not...
My error is:
"x509: ECDSA verification failure" from the crypto library of golang. And it cracks at crypto/ecdsa/ecdsa.go:

```
func verifyGeneric(pub *PublicKey, c elliptic.Curve, hash []byte, r, s *big.Int) bool {
<hidden line>
x.Mod(x, N)
return x.Cmp(r) == 0 // <-- false, always...
}
```

I would really appreciate a lead.

In order to remove any complexity regarding the CSR, I have a golang code to help me verify my signature offline. And my signature is verified. So why do you thing I am not able to verify it with csr.CheckSignature()?

```
package main

import (
    "crypto/ecdsa"
    "crypto/sha256"
    "crypto/x509"
    "encoding/asn1"
    "encoding/hex"
    "log"
    "math/big"
)

type ecdsaSignature struct {
    R *big.Int
    S *big.Int
}

const signatureHex = "304402206CE9CA4902702FFA9663F1F9C4139CFEFAE89EF1CE88CAE733F1D2BE9DDEE410022060D9C8039B0BC8A0C15B4D745DF259AED22166038CA9349BEB80F0CB7F2908C7"
const pubKeyHex = "3059301306072A8648CE3D020106082A8648CE3D030107034200046A2093D1601DB0774023BB6ECA471970F1E041D6A5CF4AEEB1402C139D4511CDD554DADC9A3F95FF9BE5A2139CE84D5BB1670525804456BA9A1F95F6F44062BC"

var message = "267f33f4035ae98b938aa0477c2831095f3656251f6d68628ae23d4a394731bb"

func main() {
    signatureBytes, err := hex.DecodeString(signatureHex)
    if err != nil {
        log.Panicln(err)
    }
    pubKeyBytes, err := hex.DecodeString(pubKeyHex)
    if err != nil {
        log.Panicln(err)
    }
    ikey, err := x509.ParsePKIXPublicKey(pubKeyBytes)
    if err != nil {
        log.Panicln(err)
    }
    pubKey := ikey.(*ecdsa.PublicKey)
    var sig ecdsaSignature
    _, err = asn1.Unmarshal(signatureBytes, &sig)
    if err != nil {
        log.Panicln(err)
    }

    h := sha256.Sum256([]byte(message))
    if ecdsa.Verify(pubKey, h[:], sig.R, sig.S) {
        log.Println("Verification succeed")
    } else {
        log.Println("Failed")
    }
}
```

Output with the same exact data: Verification succeed.

Here is an example of a valid CSR:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----
MIIBCzCBsgIBADAeMQswCQYDVQQGEwJVUzEPMA0GA1UEChMGU1BJRkZFMFkwEwYHKoZIzj0CAQYIKoZIzj0DAQcDQgAEolowNMQRxGYGvjbeBRuTuvLD0DqFE7Sy4z71zoVrg6WOtbRcvtXpSjpstCDBUmEqlo4C5LHnvnp7ZmzJ9bYZxqAyMDAGCSqGSIb3DQEJDjEjMCEwHwYDVR0RBBgwFoYUc3BpZmZlOi8vZXhhbXBsZS5vcmcwCgYIKoZIzj0EAwIDSAAwRQIhAK3vdE+nbBZblgf7i2Zx+N5JWZuylexkkq4omL3ZxO7GAiALY3mYVM1j/8Gm57Jz20shGEVh0hs1+wOGWHTc5i70/A==
-----END CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----
```

Thanks for your help...

Comment: Yes, that signature is a valid signature of the _character string_ "267f33f4...". But the data in the CSR, which is the data to be signed by the signature, is not even remotely similar to that character string, and thus that signature is not a valid signature for your CSR, and it doesn't and shouldn't verify. If you need to use a 'third-party' signer, you must have it sign the CSR data. (Treated as binary, not hex.)

Comment: PS: your last 'valid' example isn't actually valid _PEM_: that must have the base64 broken into lines of nominally 64 chars, although some programs will (at least sometimes) accept more. But if successfully parsed, it is validly signed. Also it is for a different key(pair); I assume that's intentional (e.g. it was produced by a different method that actually works right).

Comment: SOLUTION:
Perfect that was the problem. I have changed my data to be signed represented as binary when I send over the network. 
InputPayload := bytes.NewReader(data)
InputContentType := "application/octet-stream"

Thanks @dave_thompson_085